# Query expression by linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a view model in my view page that contains a list property. I want to select first item of the property and work with it.

My problem is when I use the following query expression

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var query = item.EntityCommentModels;
    var child = query.ToList().First()
    ....
    ...
}
```

I receive this error

> the sequence contains no element

but when I trace it through a `foreach` loop it works properly.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @foreach (var child in item.EntityCommentModels.Take(1))
                    {............}
}
```

What it is the reason of this problem?

Comment: Try this : `var child = query.First().ToList()`

Comment: When you say "it works properly" do you mean you see an entry, or that you don't get an exception? If you use `var list = query.ToList();` and look at that in the debugger, do you see an empty list? (That's what I'd expect.) What is the type of `item.EntityCommentModels`? If it represents a SQL query, can you look at the SQL generated in each case and execute it yourself?

Comment: @Thirisangu: No, that makes no sense - the result of `query.First()` might not even be enumerable. Using just `var child = query.First();` would make sense though - and indeed potentially be more efficient than converting the query results to a list at all.

Comment: try using `query.FirstOrDefault();` That will result in the default value (probably null) if the query returns no elements;